# JMeter: After response of specific HttpRequest, wait 3 seconds to call next request

Tags: jmeter

Using JMeter, I'm trying to test my Application Performance.

This is the first time I'm digging JMeter. So if any technical words missing, please let me know.

So going to my query,

Our application needs authentication to access any request except Login and Registration.

[image]

My Test Plan is like above.

```
A) Login Request (It should be call for every user first, then only (2) will perform)
    1) based on credential in CSV file    (Working)
    2) Post processing using BeanShell Post processor (Working)
    3) Store token and user id in variables for Next request (Working)
    4) The token will be sent through Every HttpRequest Header (Working)

B) Random Controller
   1) List of HttpRequest's 
        invoke HttpRequest randomly (Working)
   2) For Dashboard Request, after the getting the response, sleep 3 seconds and continue the flow. (only this thread will wait)
```

Now What I need is,

1) Generally, when the response received, the user reads the content. For some response are large, some are less. So reading time for content depends on content size.

Same thing I want to implement in JMeter. When Dashboard response received, wait 3 seconds(I'll specify the different time for different Req's) and then call next random HttpRequest.

I try with Http Request--> Constant Timer. But it working before request (reverse: before invoking request, wait specific time).

So is there any Timer help for my test plan design?

Also, I think about BeanShell Post processor may help. But not found anything.

Comment: jmeter is terriblely bad, give it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 options here:

1. Use Controller, Test Action, and Timer, as described [here](http://jmeter-tips.blogspot.ca/2010/01/tip-3-pauses-in-test-plan.html).
   I.e. set Transaction Controller as a parent to Dashboard Request. Add Test Action under the same controller with constant or variable pause to simulate delay:

   ```
    Random Controller
      Transaction Controller
        Dashboard Request
        Test Action
      Other HTTP Request
   ```
2. Use BeanShell, or any other programmable post-processor and the power of the corresponding language to pause. For example with BeanShell post-processor you can

   ```
   Thread.sleep(3000); // pauses for 3 sec. after request
   ```

Second solution is seems shorter and faster. But semantically first expresses the intent better.

Comment: Oh.. work as great with Test Action. Thank you, Kiril.

Comment: the blog you mention (http://jmeter-tips.blogspot.in ) is very helpful. thanks to Victor Klepikovskiy